# cv2.imshow and numpy.dstack core dumped

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I am trying to stack two images together, so i can show both in a single window.
First image is the original, 3-channel image, second one is a gray version.
I did the color conversion with cv2.cvtColor, transformed back to 3-channel with **numpy.dstack**,
and when i try **cv2.imshow**, it gives me a "**core dumped**" error.
Am i missing something? I need both images to have the same number of channels to stack them
with numpy.hstack. This happens on a Ubuntu 64bit machine.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("/home/bernie/Dropbox/Python/Opencv/lena512.jpg")

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = np.dstack((gray,gray,gray))

#res = np.hstack((img,gray))

print gray.dtype
print gray.shape

cv2.imshow('gray',gray)
#cv2.imshow('res',res)
cv2.waitKey()
```

---

### addition

On the other hand, using

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(gray,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
```

in **line 7** works without complaints, so i will stick to this for now. This means that there is a difference
between
the **cv2.cvtColor** result and **numpy.dstack** result for turning a 1-channel image to 3-channel with equal values.

Comment: [See this post](http://answers.opencv.org/question/373/cv2-bindings-incompatible-with-numpydstack/)

Comment: Thank you fraxel, this answered my question.

Comment: @fraxel can you write that link up as an answer?

Comment: There should be not core dump no matter how you call cv.imshow. See https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/501

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, try using `cv2.merge` since apparently it's strided differently from `np.dstack`:

```
gray = cv2.merge([gray]*3)
```

See @[fraxel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175101/fraxel)'s [link for more info](http://answers.opencv.org/question/373/cv2-bindings-incompatible-with-numpydstack/)